# How to prevent the page load twice when dynamically adding the button?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have dynamically created button in c#, button is bind to page on page load event of page

Now, when I press the button from them then page loading twice, it is like page refreshing
How can I stop that re-binding of control when I click button?
my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  if (!IsPostBack) {} 
  else 
  { 
    fillquotes(); 
  } 
} 

fillquotes() 
{ 
  //dynamicaaly create the button 
  msg.OnClientClick="lnkmsg(" + i + ")"; 
} 

btnMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
------ 
}
```

client side:

```
function lnkmsg(id) 
{ 
  __doPostBack('<%= btnMsg.UniqueID %>', ""); 

}
```

when msg button clicks

1. pageload
2. msg_click()
3. pageload
4. msg_click()

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it by setting condition for checking Request.Form["__EventTarget"]. Check the spelling and syntax for it. May this solve your problem.

Enjoy Coding!!!